# C: Remaining bytes on AF_UNIX socket

Tags: c, sockets

I got some problems with `AF_UNIX` socket communication because after writing a data buffer there seem to remain some hanging bytes to read that I do not know where they come from.

I am writing a multithreaded server program in C that communicates with clients through `AF_UNIX` sockets, it must implement a simple chatroom. Among other things, the server must implement file transfers between clients and servers and i encountered  problems when i try to send a quite large file (269K) from Server to client. (With smaller files i do not have any problems)

For file transfer i use `mmap()` function which return a pointer to the map of the file I want to send, then i use `write()` for write that data on socket linked with the client that must recieve the file.
After `write()` call i check the returned value to be equal than the file size. (always verified)

The client, after receiving the file, check the size of read data  (always verified) and start waiting for other messages so it call a blocking `read()`. **This** is the point where I found the error because the client reads something that should not be there, **as if there was something left to read on the socket**.
I've been debugging this part (both server and client) for two days and I have not yet been able to understand the origin of the problem.

**I am sure that no other thread write on the same socket at the same time**

Does any of you have an idea of what the cause of this error is?

I try to post some useful code thinking at a normal operation sequence:

First of all message structure:

```
struct message_hdr
{
    op_t     op; 
    char sender[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
};

struct message_data_hdr{
    char receiver[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
    unsigned int   len;
};

struct message_data
{
    message_data_hdr_t hdr;
    char *buf;
};

struct message
{
    message_hdr_t  hdr;
    message_data_t data;
};
```

A server->client file transfer starts with server that send a `message_hdr_t` to a client which is waiting on a `read()` (the client expects to receive only a `message_hdr_t`).

```
int sendHeader(long fd, message_hdr_t* hdr)
{
    if(hdr == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;
    struct iovec iov;

    iov.iov_base = hdr;
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(message_hdr_t);

    test = writev(fd, &iov, 1);

    return  test;
}
```

The client understands from the operation code (`message.hdr.op`) that it is a file type message and it begins to wait for file,

So server send it:

```
int sendData(long fd, message_data_t *msg)
{
    if(msg == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;
    struct iovec iov;

    iov.iov_base = &(msg->hdr);
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(message_data_hdr_t);

    test = writev(fd, &(iov), 1);
    if(test == -1){return -1;}

    if (msg->hdr.len != 0)
    {
        test = write(fd, msg->buf, msg->hdr.len);
        if(test <= 0)
            return -1;
    }

    return test;
}
```

And client read it:

```
int readData(long fd, message_data_t *data)
{
    if(data == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;
    struct iovec iov;

    iov.iov_base = &(data->hdr);
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(message_data_hdr_t);

    test = readv(fd, &iov, 1);
    if(test <= 0){return -1;}

    if(data->hdr.len != 0)
    {
        data->buf = malloc(data->hdr.len);
        if(data->buf == NULL){return -1;}

        test = read(fd, data->buf, data->hdr.len);
        if((unsigned int)test != data->hdr.len)
            return -1;
    }

    return test;
}
```

At this point the client recived file, and it restart waiting for new messages:

```
int readMsg(long fd, message_t *msg)
{
    if(msg == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;

    test = readHeader(fd, &(msg->hdr));
    if(test == -1 || test == 0){return -1;}

    test += readData(fd, &(msg->data));
    return test;
}
```

This is the point where the client should simply wait because there is no income messages, insted in this case it read something that I do not know where it comes from.

When i try to print this unwanted message with GDB  it prints:

```
{hdr = {op = 512, 
        sender = "\000\000\020G\032\324\t\000\000\n\000\000\000\000\030\021B\bC\n\000\000\v\000\000\000\000\021D\v\222\000"}, 
 data = {hdr = {receiver = "\000\000\000\000\021E\022C\n\000\000\b\v\000\000\000\000\021F\020I\n\000\000\020\000\006\b\002\n\000\000\006", 
         len = 131072}, 
 buf = 0x7ffff7f2f010 ""}`
```

Of course this is meaningless.

I hope that this description will be useful

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should show the (if necessary simplified) source code to allow us to find problems. Sending the complete block of data may exceed some buffer size, so you should be prepared for `write` to have written only a part of the data. Similar for `read`.

Comment: 1. use send/recv for socket communication. 2. do not assume that recv/send fully received or send the data (so keep trying after a small sleep) 3. always handle zero recv/send case as connection closed.

Comment: @Bodo Ok i added some code, i hope that is useful. Anyway when i debug i test the return value of both `read()` and `write()`  and they result to be correct (the size of the file). Are you saying that even in the case of buffer size exceeding,  the 'write()` call return the requested size?

Comment: Try to send a file with contents that is easy to recognize, e.g. binary data `{ 0x55, 0xAA, 0x55, 0xAA, ...}`. Maybe you will see that you receive parts of the file as a new header. Your communication protocol is fragile. When you receive the file size in your header and the receiver does not receive the expected amount of data you don't know if the sender sent less than expected or if something failed (e.g. buffer full) in the receiver. So you don't know if you have to read the missing bytes before expecting the next header or not.

Comment: `write` and `read` return the number of bytes written or read. The functions will tell you when they have written or read only a part of your data. When you run your program in a debugger it may run slower, so it might behave different, so you should handle partial reads or writes in your code.

Comment: @Bodo You are right!
I modified code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570172/7996173) and now it works.
I think this is what you meant. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue.
As written in the comment, this problem was due to the **lack of a check on partial writing.**

Now the function `readData()` looks like this:

```
int readData(long fd, message_data_t *data)
{
    if(data == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;
    char* ph;
    unsigned int rd = 0;
    struct iovec iov;

    iov.iov_base = &(data->hdr);
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(message_data_hdr_t);

    test = readv(fd, &iov, 1);
    if(test <= 0){return -1;}

    if(data->hdr.len != 0)
    {
        data->buf = malloc(data->hdr.len);
        if(data->buf == NULL){return -1;}

        ph = data->buf;

        while (rd < data->hdr.len)
        {
            test = read(fd, ph, data->hdr.len - rd);
            if(test ==  -1)
                return -1;
            else if(test == 0)
            {
                errno = ENOENT;
                return -1;
            }

            rd += test;
            ph += test;
        }
    }

    return rd;
}
```

and `sendData()`:

```
int sendData(long fd, message_data_t *msg)
{
    if(msg == NULL || fd < 0) {errno = EINVAL; return -1;}

    int test;
    char* ph;
    unsigned int wr = 0;
    struct iovec iov;

    iov.iov_base = &(msg->hdr);
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(message_data_hdr_t);

    test = writev(fd, &(iov), 1);
    if(test == -1){return -1;}

    if(msg->hdr.len != 0)
    {
        ph = msg->buf;

        while (wr < msg->hdr.len)
        {
            test = write(fd, ph, msg->hdr.len - wr);
            if(test ==  -1)
                return -1;
            else if(test == 0)
            {
                errno = ENOENT;
                return -1;
            }

            wr += test;
            ph += test;
        }
    }

    return test;
}
```

In this way I no longer found the error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This code doesn't work. It needs to advance the buffer pointer and decrement the length required. You should not treat 0 (end of stream) and -1 (error) as the same. They aren't. You will find further issues that are hard to debug unless you fix this,

Comment: @user207421 you are right, I gave a hasty reply. I correct it now

Comment: @user207421 Now it should be corect